# Compress Image In Javascript using Telerik AsyncUpload

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik

I have created a javascript function that compresses the JPEG image. It is working fine for JPEG files. But even user can upload xls,doc,pdf etc as well. So its breaking for any other files except JPG/JPEG. User can also upload other types of files as well. Only the JPG/JPEG needs to be compressed.

Else part is working perfectly fine. Need to fix the If part.

```
function OnClientFileSelected(radAsyncUpload, args) {
        var old_uploadFile = radAsyncUpload._uploadModule._uploadFile;
        var fileName = args.get_fileName();
        var fileExtention = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1, fileName.length);
        if (fileExtention.toLowerCase() != 'jpg' && fileExtention.toLowerCase() != 'jpeg') {
            radAsyncUpload._uploadModule._uploadFile = function (pair) {
                var uploadFile = pair.file;
                //return uploadFile;
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(uploadFile);
            }
        }
        else {
            radAsyncUpload._uploadModule._uploadFile = function (pair) {
                var uploadFile = pair.file;

                var img = document.createElement("img");
                var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    img.src = e.target.result
                    img.onload = function () {
                        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

                        var greaterDimension = 0;
                        var newPixelMultiplier = 1;

                        if (img.width > img.height)
                            greaterDimension = img.width;
                        else
                            greaterDimension = img.height;

                        if (greaterDimension > 1000) {
                            newPixelMultiplier = ((((greaterDimension - 1000) / 2) + 1000) / greaterDimension);
                        }

                        var MAX_WIDTH = img.width * newPixelMultiplier;
                        var MAX_HEIGHT = img.height * newPixelMultiplier;
                        var width = img.width;
                        var height = img.height;

                        if (width > height) {
                            if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                                height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                                width = MAX_WIDTH;
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                                width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                                height = MAX_HEIGHT;
                            }
                        }
                        canvas.width = width;
                        canvas.height = height;

                        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);


                        canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
                            blob.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
                            blob.name = pair.file.name;
                            pair.file = blob;

                            old_uploadFile.call(this, pair)

                        }, 'image/jpeg', 0.6); //Set the Quality of Image...
                    }
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(uploadFile);

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the code for the resizing is from the following KB article: [Preview uploaded image with RadAsyncUpload](https://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/upload-(async)/details/preview-uploaded-image-with-radasyncupload).

If that is the case, I can suggest that you that you keep the code as it is, or use it in the OnClientLoad event of the AsyncUpload control, as in your case it will be overridden on every file that is being selected.

Regarding your question in point, I can suggest you try to call the old_uploadFile as follows:

```
if (/*is not image condition here*/) {
   old_uploadFile.call(radAsyncUpload, pair);
}
```

If the code from the KB is used, then it should be similar to this:

```
asyncupload._uploadModule._uploadFile = function (pair) {
    var uploadFile = pair.file;
    if (/*is not image condition here*/) {
        old_uploadFile.call(this, pair);
        return;
    }

    // rest of code for resizing images here
}
```

Comment: Its working fine if I add any other file before uploading image file. But if i upload an image file, it compresses the image and then upload it. And then if i try to upload any other file then it doesn't work. it just stuck with the progress bar.